# When will the drug events api (https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json) be updated with 2018 Q2 data

Tags: openfda, drugs

I see that on the FDA adverse events reporting (FAERS) public dashboard the data is already as of June 30, 2018 whereas on the API its still as of March 31, 2018.

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:20180101+TO+20180813&count=receivedate

or

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receiptdate:20180101+TO+20180813&count=receiptdate

> {
>        "time": "20180329",
>        "count": 288
>      },
>      {
>        "time": "20180330",
>        "count": 237
>      },
>      {
>        "time": "20180331",
>        "count": 20
>      }
>    ]
>   }

[image: FAERS Public Dashboard with data as of June 30, 2018]

Comment: I'm afraid this is something that we can't answer unless there's an official announcement about it (which it might be, or it might be not).

Comment: @AndrewT. I see, I am new to the openFDA API. So, there is a lag between when the quarterly files are posted to FAERS/public dashboard and when the openFDA is updated. Do you know what is the typical lag? couple of weeks? Thanks.

Comment: Based on [the discussion on OpenFDA GitHub](https://github.com/FDA/openfda/issues/24), it should be "every other week on Wednesday night". However, looks like it's not the case here. Probably it's better to report this on there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please check back next week for the updates.

Comment: The author isn't even asking a question

Comment: He is, in the title. I agree that repeating the question in the text would've been nice.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant? Please flag if not.